# Index out of range when initialise an array (swift)

Tags: swift

```
struct GroupStruct {
var groupName = " "
var groupAge= " "
var tests: [TestStruct] = []
}

struct TestStruct {
var desc= " "
var title= " "
}
```

Index out of range when GroupStruct.tests[0].desc = "abc" .
why did that happen? thanks for helping.

Comment: because its empty? have you initialize `GroupStruct.tests`? have you add any `TestStruct`?

Comment: `GroupStruct.tests[0].groupName = "abc"` - I see three mistakes in this line. Try to rethink what are you doing and what are you need to achieve

Comment: how to initialise GroupStruct.tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must initialize the GroupStruct.
Then add the a new element on it.

```
import Foundation

struct GroupStruct {
    var groupName = " "
    var groupAge = " "
    var tests: [TestStruct] = []
}

struct TestStruct {
    var desc = " "
    var title = " "
}

// Creates a new instance of GroupStruct
var groupStruct = GroupStruct()

// Appends a new instance of TestStruct (will be at index 0)
groupStruct.tests.append(TestStruct(desc: "abd", title: ""))
```

Comment: It seems it will start at index 1 instead of 0

Comment: Not really, the list is initialized but is empty, It will be added at index 0. Try print(groupStruct.tests[0]) and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
var groupStruct = GroupStruct() // Declare groupStruct instance
var TestStructObj = TestStruct(desc: "abc", title: "abc") // Create TestStruct instance
groupStruct.tests.append(TestStructObj) // Append it to tests array
```

Tip - declare the array this way:

```
var tests = [TestStruct]()
```

Comment: It will not add on the GroupStruct array, only on the "tests" array.